# Set SQLite connection properties in c3p0 connection pool

Tags: java, sqlite, c3p0

To specify SQLite connection properties there is org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig and it goes something like this:

```
    org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig config = new org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig();
    config.setReadOnly(true);
    config.setPageSize(4096); //in bytes
    config.setCacheSize(2000); //number of pages
    config.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.OFF);
    config.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.OFF);
    SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource();
```

Creating a connection pool with c3p0 goes something like this:

```
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlite:/foo/bar");
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
```

Question: how do I create a DataSource that combines the two, letting me set things like the connection pool's max-pool-size and sqlite's synchronous mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
//put the imports where they really go, obviously...
import javax.sql.*;
import org.sqlite.*;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*;

// configure SQLite
SQLiteConfig config = new org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig();
config.setReadOnly(true);
config.setPageSize(4096); //in bytes
config.setCacheSize(2000); //number of pages
config.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.OFF);
config.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.OFF);

// get an unpooled SQLite DataSource with the desired configuration
SQLiteDataSource unpooled = new SQLiteDataSource( config );

// get a pooled c3p0 DataSource that wraps the unpooled SQLite DataSource
DataSource pooled = DataSources.pooledDataSource( unpooled );
```

The DataSource `pooled` will now be a c3p0 PooledDataSource that wraps an SQLite unpooled DataSource which has been configured as you wish.

Please see c3p0's docs, ["Using the DataSources factory class"](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_datasources_factory), and the API docs for the [DataSources](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources.html) factory class.

See also the javadocs for SQLite JDBC, which I downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads) to answer this question.

Comment: Don't you need a ConnectionPoolDataSource?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. What I meant to ask is this: SQLite has a ConnectionPoolDataSource. Is there any advantage to using that?

Comment: no, you are probably better off using the simple DataSource and letting c3p0 provide its own ConnectionPoolDataSource. You can have c3p0 wrap a driver's ConnectionPoolDataSource (see c3p0's docs, something like "Advanced: Build your own DataSource"), but you'll lose access to some c3p0 features and usually gain very little by doing that.

Comment: This works, but since I'm new to this, it took me a bit to figure out that I had to use `unpooled.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath);` instead of `unpooled.setDatabaseName(dbPath);` to specify which database I want to connect to. I saw weird errors until I did this.

Comment: How to get a ConnectionPoolDataSource from this? The example shows how to get a DataSource, but not how to get a ConnectionPoolDataSource