# c3p0 connection pooling, DataSources factory, how do I close the pool?

Tags: java, postgresql, sqlite, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm trying to use [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0) for connection pooling with both PostgreSQL and SQLite. The PostgreSQL side works no problem. I've [followed the directions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303796/set-sqlite-connection-properties-in-c3p0-connection-pool), but I don't understand how to close the SQLite side down when I'm done with it.

In other words, on the PostgreSQL side, where I'm using a `ComboPooledDataSource`, I can call `.close()` on my `ComboPooledDataSource` as shown [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#quickstart). I feel like there should be a `.close()` for the SQLite side too, but I don't see one on the `DataSource`.

How do I close down the SQLite side appropriately? Do I even need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `DataSources.pooledDataSource` javadoc:

> @return a DataSource that can be cast to a {@link PooledDataSource} if you are interested in pool statistics

And `PooledDataSource` has `close` method.