# Get SQLite read-only C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, datasource, c3p0

I need to get a SQLite read-only C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource. This code I found here ([Set SQLite connection properties in c3p0 connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303796/set-sqlite-connection-properties-in-c3p0-connection-pool)) creates a SQLite read-only DataSource:

```
//put the imports where they really go, obviously...
import javax.sql.*;
import org.sqlite.*;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*;

// configure SQLite
SQLiteConfig config = new org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig();
config.setReadOnly(true);
config.setPageSize(4096); //in bytes
config.setCacheSize(2000); //number of pages
config.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.OFF);
config.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.OFF);

// get an unpooled SQLite DataSource with the desired configuration
SQLiteDataSource unpooled = new SQLiteDataSource( config );

// get a pooled c3p0 DataSource that wraps the unpooled SQLite DataSource
DataSource pooled = DataSources.pooledDataSource( unpooled );
```

It works fine. But the method I am trying to adapt returns a ComboPooledDataSource. How can I get one ?

Comment: I just need to get read-only connections for SQLite using C3P0. I tried with the recommended ConnectionCustomizer but I get the error message: Cannot change read-only flag after establishing a connection. Use SQLiteConfig#setReadOnly and SQLiteConfig.createConnection(). so the connection has to be set to readOnly before it is created. The code above works, just that I need a ComboPooledDataSource instead of a DataSource

Comment: Did you tried my answer to use HikariCP?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, [C3P0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) update readonly **after** connection created

> Occasionally it is useful to override the default values of standard Connection properties such as transactionIsolation, holdability, or **readOnly. c3p0 provides a "hook" interface** that you can implement, which gives you the opportunity to **modify or track Connections just after they are checked out from the database**, immediately just prior to being handed to clients on checkout, just prior to being returned to the pool on check-in, and just prior to final destruction by the pool. The Connections handed to ConnectionCustomizers are raw, physical Connections, with all vendor-specific API accessible. See the API docs for ConnectionCustomizer.

I would suggest, do a switch, similar to Spring framework, from C3P0 to [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) connection pool

HikariCP allows you to set readOnly property:

> readOnly
>   This property controls whether **Connections obtained from the pool are in read-only mode by default**. Note some databases do not support the concept of read-only mode, while others provide query optimizations when the Connection is set to read-only. Whether you need this property or not will depend largely on your application and database. Default: false